# angular 8, looping through grouped data

Tags: angular, grouping, ngfor

I've got a json file with a data field. I've been trying multiple ways to grou the data by the date and present it grouped with ngFor. None of the ways worked, and I really need someone's help. Is there a way to loop through the 'datagrouped'?, All i want is to display data grouped by the date value like in example below:
27/11/19
task title1
task title2

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import  *  as  data  from  '../data.json';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tasklist',
  templateUrl: './tasklist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tasklist.component.css']
})
export class TasklistComponent implements OnInit {

  mockData: any  = (data  as  any).default;

  show: boolean = false;
  value: string;
  id: number;
  array = this.mockData;
  datagrouped = _.groupBy(this.array, "date");

  constructor(private router: Router ) {}

  remove(id) {
    this.mockData = this.mockData.filter(item => {
      if (item.id !== id) {
        return item;
      }
    });
  }


  create(item) {

    this.datagrouped.push({
      id: Date.now(),
      title: item,
      done: false,
      date: new Date()
    });

  }

  update(title) {
    this.mockData.map(item => {
      if (item.id === this.id) {
        item['title'] = title;
      }
    });

    this.show = false;
  }

  edit(id, title) {
    this.show = true;
    this.value = title;
    this.id = id;
  }

  setTaskComplete(id) {
    this.mockData.map(item => {
      if (item.id === id) {
        item['done'] = true;
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

```
<p>tasklist works!</p>
<div class="col-sm-12 pt-5 text-right">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="edit-popup" *ngIf="show">
            <input type="text" name="" class="edit-item" value="{{value}}" #item>
            <button class="btn-primary" (click)="update(item.value)">Update</button>

          </div>
          <input type="text" name="" class="item" #item>
          <button class="btn-primary" (click)="create(item.value)">Add</button>

  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-12 pt-2">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
            <thead class="table-primary">
                <tr>

                    <th scope="col">Task</th>
                    <th scope="col">Date</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="text-center">Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let item of datagrouped ">

                    <td>{{item.title}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.date | date: 'shortDate'}}</td>
                    <td width="150" class="text-center">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm mr-2" (click)="edit(item.id, item.title)">Edit</button> 
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" (click)="remove(item.id)">Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "title": "This is the longest task ever.",
    "done": false,
    "date": "333"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "This is the second longest task ever.",
    "done": true,
    "date": "444"
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "title": "This is the third longest task ever.",
    "done": false,
    "date": "333"
}, {
    "id": "4",
    "title": "This is the fourth longest task ever.",
    "done": false,
    "date": "444"
}]
``
```

Comment: hey, can you provide us a stackblitz with an example of what you're trying to do ? :)

Answer (score 0):

27/11/19 task title1 task title2

Group function for your component:

```
group(arr:any){
  let dates:any = {};
  arr.forEach((data) => {
    dates[data.date] = null;
  });
  dates = Object.keys(dates);

  let datagrouped = {};
  dates.forEach((date) => {
    datagrouped[date] = arr.reduce((dataArr, data) => {
      if(data.date == date){
        dataArr.push(data);
      }
      return dataArr;
    }, []);
  });
}
```

The structure in this case should look like this (I did not test the code):

```
// datagrouped = 
//   {
//     date1: [
//       {...},
//       {...}
//     ],
//     date2 : ...,
//   }
//
```

So you can call:

```
this.datagrouped = this.group(this.mockData);
```

And in your template you can loop through like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let date of datagrouped|keys">
  <span>{{date}}</span>
  <span *ngFor="let item of datagrouped[date]">task {{item.title}} </span>
</div>
```

If you implement keys pipe and add it to your AppModule

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'keys'
})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value:object|Map<any, any>): any {
      if(value instanceof Map){ return Array.from(value.keys()); }
      return Object.keys(value);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help. The solution works, however, the buttons the buttons next to the results now don't. They used to triffer the edit function which took item.id and item.title parameters.

Comment: @Marcin Are you sure? The edit and remove functions should get the right parameters. Could you modify the functions to console.log() the id and the title please?